# What should I do with warnings that show up after upgrading to ARC code?

Tags: xcode4, automatic-ref-counting, compiler-warnings

I got 213 warning.

Here are some and their issues:

UserController.m:

> ARC Issue — Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will
>   be released after assignment V r’

LoginController.m

> ARC Issue — Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released
>   after assignment

Well, I checked that the object is declared without strong or retain. However, default for ARC files are strong, NOT assign.

Does the compiler still think that the files are non ARC files? Where can I check?

> Semantic Issue No ‘assign’, ‘retain’, or ‘copy’ attribute is specified
>   — ‘assign’ is assumed
>
> Semantic Issue Default property attribute ‘assign’ not appropriate for
>   non-gc object
>
> Semantic Issue No ‘assign’, ‘retain’, or ‘copy’ attribute is specified
>   — ‘assign’ is assumed
>
> Semantic Issue Again, no attribute is specified means RETAIN should be
>   assumed, which is the new default for ARC files.

Those things show up on codes generated automatically by the coredata.

Should I just ignore those warnings?

But it's too anoying

Replacing the code one by one is too time consuming. Also that means I am not taking advantage of the fact that the default is indeed strong.

Maybe I can search and replace. What exact format should I search and replace for?

Programs are working fine.

[image]

Comment: Show us the code for UserController.m for where the first type of error is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I would just turn off ARC for the current project and work with it during the next new project that you create. going from non-ARC to ARC is such a pain D: